# Best Way to Implement this App

Tags: android, sqlite

Im making a workout app and just would like to clarify that the way Im thinking of doing it is the best and most efficient way.

I am creating a workout app and plan to have 150+ excercises with descriptions and pictures. I plan on allowing the user to **create, log and arrange exercises(both the original and the new ones they have created)** to suit their needs. Am I correct in thinking the best way to do this would be to implement a SQLite database? Would rather not have the need to connect to the internet so want the database in the android.

Thanks

Comment: IMHO, yes, that's the way to go. Now the remaining is *HOW* to structure your DB correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a trend these days to move away from textual representation, into audio and video. It will be great if you can categorize and search for audio/video for exercises based on my body structure (may be medical complications) and what I expect my body structure to be. Example scenarios

1. A lady with a low back issue, will be advised to do stomach exercises differently, if she wants to reduce her waist.
2. A lady with acute back issue, will be advised to walk in water, instead of hard ground.
3. A professional with very less time in his hands may want to use his stairs for exercises, may be you can tell him what he should/should not do. How many floors and what to watch out for. Some kinda guide / personal trainer.

Here you need to blend a "good trainer advice" with the audio's / video's you may have for these exercises.

It will be good if you can choose a trainer :), I mean I may want a lady trainer :).

Do think about making it fun too...

Walk into a gym and interview some trainers, and people who visit the gym. Visit some shopping malls and talk to people who have a higher BMI. Research Research Research.

If you can get your requirements right, your technical skills will be rewarded with. Dont hurry into it, its a good idea.

Edited

If this is a stand alone app, audio and video will make it really heavy. Instead use a webservice of some kind, on a server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you do not need remote database. SQLite is just perfect !